# Is Pomeranchuk's theorem true?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I finished reading an essay about accelerator technology (https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06036), where Pomeranchuk's theorem veracity is cited as a question (in a list of particle physics questions from almost 50 years ago).

Looking up in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomeranchuk%27s_theorem) I could not find if the answer is yes or no for my question (I could not look at the reference cited there, though) and a proof thereof. According to the previous link,

> Pomeranchuk's theorem states that difference of cross sections of
>   interactions of elementary particles ${\displaystyle \kappa_{1}+\kappa _{2}}$ 
>   and ${\displaystyle \kappa_{1}+{\bar {\kappa _{2}}}}$  approach 0 when ${\displaystyle s\to \infty }$, where $s$ is the energy in center of mass system.

So, is the theorem true or not?

Comment: "Sun is the same in a relative way, but you are older..."(Pink Floyd).

Pomeranchuk's theorem does not take into account all perturbative corrections, among which are soft photon corrections. For two charges different in sign the radiation is more powerful than for two one-sign charges. So the theorem may be "true" in a relative sense, not in an "absolute value" one, I guess.